# How do you get the thumbprint out of win_certificate_store?

Tags: ansible

I'm wondering after running win_certificate_store to add the certificate, how do you get the thumbprint out? There's a return value but I'm not too sure how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I did the following:

- import a Root CA using PKCS12 format into Windows truststore
- display thumbprint of the imported certificate
- export the Root CA certificate in der format by using the previous thumbprint

  ```
    - name: Import Root-CA in Windows truststore
      win_certificate_store:
        path: 'C:\logstash\cert\root_ca_truststore.pfx'
        file_type: pkcs12
        password: "{{ root_ca_truststore_pwd }}"
        key_storage: machine
        store_name: Root
        state: present
      register: _root_ca_cert

    - name: Show RootCA certificate Thumbprint 
      debug:
        msg: "Root CA Thumbprint ={{ _root_ca_cert.thumbprints }}"

    - name: ensure RootCA certificate is exported as .cer format
      win_certificate_store:
        thumbprint: "{{ _root_ca_cert.thumbprints | first }}"
        file_type: der
        key_storage: machine
        store_name: Root
        path: 'C:\logstash\cert\root-ca-export.cer'
        state: exported
  ```

In this example Ansible returns to you a list of thumbprints.

Select only the first element on your thumbprints list by using: `{{ _root_ca_cert.thumbprints | first }}`.

If you provide the entire list of thumbprints the export will fail.

For me was safe to do that because this root_ca_truststore.pfx only has a public key and there is no problem exporting it without providing a password. Do not recommend doing this if your pfx file contains a private key.

This was only to trust a RootCA and export it with a different format.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to register the output of the win_certificate_store module and then extract it from the register variable ( cert_import in this example ) like so ...

```
- name: Import certificate be used by IIS
  win_certificate_store:
    path: 'C:\Temp\certs\iis_certificate.pfx'
    file_type: pkcs12
    password: 
    store_location: LocalMachine
    key_storage: machine
    state: present
  register: cert_import  # this will contain the thumbprint of the cert

- name: debug
  debug:
    msg: " Thumbprint = {{ cert_import.thumbprints }} "
```

**Output:**

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [svrt00008d6d.tus.ams1907.com] =>
  msg: ' Thumbprint = [u''5FFB05315039310F1CABFA80BCDDAB5926123456''] '
```